# Can OS X 10.5.8 be installed on a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 Mac Mini?

Tags: snow-leopard, upgrade, mac-mini, osx-server, leopard

Can OS X 10.5.8 be installed on a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 Mac Mini
in order to upgrade to OS X 10.6.3 server?
(The Goal: to quit 10.8 Server in order to use Rosetta software again)

Answer (score 1):

Your Mac mini is probably a [Apple Mac mini "Core i7" 2.3 (Late 2012) Macmini6,2](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i7-2.3-late-2012-specs.html). It was originally delivered with Mac OS X 10.8.1.

Neither 10.5 nor 10.6 contain the necessary drivers to support your hardware (especially USB3.0).

Consider installing Mac OS X Server 10.6.8 in an virtual machine using [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/), [VMware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/) (both non-free) or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) (free).

Answer (score 0):

No. 10.5 doesn't include the necessary drivers for your machine, neither does 10.6

One option would be to install 10.6 Server in a Virtual Machine. There are a few tutorials on the net, it can be quiet tricky as I recall but it works.

Comment: I've installed Mac OS X 10.6.3 Snow Leopard Server (a retail unbundled version) under VMware Fusion, several times and different versions of VMware Fusion, and it was just as straight forward as installing it on physical Apple-branded hardware.  Most all the issues I've read about was when using other then a retail unbundled version of earlier then Mac OS X 10.6.3 Snow Leopard Server.  This is with VMware Fusion, never installed it under Parallels and only once under VirtualBox and no issue with it there either.

Comment: Okay good to hear. I once did it in Parallels 10 and it was a real pain. I believe they don't officially support it anymore in the newest version. The install it self was quick, but getting things like audio to work was a bit of a hack.